# Rails: Multiple layouts with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise, view

How can I have a completely different layout depending on wether a user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions at
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts
and make the check be if the user is logged in, which for devise means checking
`user_signed_in?`, which is a devise helper.

Specifically:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if user_signed_in?
      "special_layout_name_for_logged_in"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

and put the `special_layout_for_logged_in.html.erb` view file in the layouts directory.